# Objective-C access another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Objective-C newbie here.

I've been looking at this for way too long and decided to ask for help.

I have ViewController and TestClass.  I want to message a method from TestClass called TestMethod in ViewController.  Being from the C# world I would do:

```
TestClass testClass = new TestClass(); 
testClass.TestMethod();
```

I've searched for too long and haven't found a simple solution.  All of the examples I've found either don't work or don't fit what I'm trying to do.

TestClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TestClass : NSObject

@end
```

TestClass.m

```
#import "TestClass.h"

@implementation TestClass

-(void)testMethod {

}
```

ViewController.h

```
#import "TestClass.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

TestClass *testClass;

@interface ViewController()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [testClass testMethod];
}
```

What am I missing?!?!

Comment: You're right.  Removed.

Comment: FYI - In your `ViewController.m` you have `TestClass *testClass;` floating in the middle of nowhere. This is unlikely to be what you want because this creates a file global variable. If you intend to make that an instance variable it needs to be declared in the proper place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're missing is the equivalent of the line with `new TestClass` in it.

```
TestClass *testObject = [[TestClass alloc] init];
[testObject testMethod];
```

Also, put a declaration of your method into the TestClass.h interface.

```
-(void)testMethod;
```

And, it's a good idea to put...

```
#import "TestClass.h"
```

...into your ViewController.m file instead of your .h unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: The -(void)testMethod did the trick.  I had something similar to the first part of the answer although a bit convoluted.

Comment: Curious, why put the import in the  .m?

Comment: The import should go to the source (.m) because it's not necessary in the header. Headers are intended for all external clients that need to know about your class, and they should only contain the information that is necessary to advertise. Since nothing else in your header depends on knowing the contents of testclass.h, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: I agree with @mah and will add that putting unnecessary imports into .h files will someday get you circular references, which are less than fun.  :)  (This is why Objective-C has a `@class` notation.)